# How to get a word probability according to a context with word2vec?

Tags: python, probability, cpu-word, word2vec

I am using word2vec in python to create vector representations of words from various descriptions. 
I have trained my model with my corpus of descriptions.

Now, for a given sentence S and a given word W, I would like to know the probability of generating the word W in the context S. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Do you have any code that shows that you've tried something that we could use to help you with the problems you've encountered?